# Получение данных из ячеек

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, парсер

Каким образом можно вытащить значения- 1,2,3 из таблицы "Journal"? Не нашел подходящую библиотеку. **Хочу сделать запрос через requests, и вытащить значение из таблицы.** Имеется таблица вида:

```html
<table id="journal" class="marks">
<tbody>
<tr>'
<td class="s2">
<strong class="u">HTML</strong>
</td>
<td class="tac">
<span class="mark mY analytics-app-popup-mark" data-num="0">1</span>
<span class="mark mY analytics-app-popup-mark" data-num="0">2</span>
<span class="mark mG analytics-app-popup-mark" data-num="0">3</span>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используя `lxml`:

```
from lxml import html

text = """
<table id="journal" class="marks">
<tbody>
<tr>'
<td class="s2">
<strong class="u">HTML</strong>
</td>
<td class="tac">
<span class="mark mY analytics-app-popup-mark" data-num="0">1</span>
<span class="mark mY analytics-app-popup-mark" data-num="0">2</span>
<span class="mark mG analytics-app-popup-mark" data-num="0">3</span>
</td>
"""

root = html.fromstring(text)
items = root.xpath('//td/span/text()')
print(items)  # ['1', '2', '3']
```

---

**PS.** тот `xpath` запрос можно уточнить указав таблицу (и при желании класс): `'//table[@id="journal"]//td/span/text()'`, но получится что-то очень громоздкое:  `'//table[@id="journal"]//td[@class="tac"]/span[contains(@class, "mark")]/text()'`

Comment: Спасибо, это работает, но как вывести данные из определенного тега tr, а если быть точнее, как указать индекс?

Comment: @0x00 `xpath` вернет список элементов, поэтому если сделаете например так `root.xpath('//table[@id="journal"]//tr')`, то получите список tr, а там уже как с обычными списками можете по индексу обращаться.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте `PyQuery`

```
from pyquery import PyQuery as pq
table = pq(*тут ваш хтмл-текст*)
for c in table('tbody tr td'):
   if c.text == True:
       print c.text
   else:
       continue
```

Comment: Ветка с `else` лишняя, а `if c.text == True` выглядит странно, мб вы имели ввиду просто `if c.text`?. А сам цикл можно в генератор списка превратить, будет что-то такое: `items = [c.text for c in table('tbody tr td') if c.text]`

Comment: @gil9red согласен!

Comment: Дело в том, что у каждого пользователя будут разные значения в теге <span>, которые я не знаю, и мне нужно будет их получить.

Answer (score 2):

Используя `BeautifulSoup`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

text = """
<table id="journal" class="marks">
<tbody>
<tr>'
<td class="s2">
<strong class="u">HTML</strong>
</td>
<td class="tac">
<span class="mark mY analytics-app-popup-mark" data-num="0">1</span>
<span class="mark mY analytics-app-popup-mark" data-num="0">2</span>
<span class="mark mG analytics-app-popup-mark" data-num="0">3</span>
</td>
"""

root = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
items = [i.text for i in root.select('td > span')]
print(items)  # ['1', '2', '3']
```

**PS.** в css-селекторе можно и уточнить класс, и таблицу: `'#journal td.tac > span.mark'`

Comment: Дело в том, что у каждого пользователя будут разные значения в теге <span>, которые я не знаю, и мне нужно будет их получить.

Comment: У каждого пользователя будет таблица "Journal", но значения будут у всех разные.

Comment: Не может у каждого быть такая таблица (в рамках одного документа), т.к. `id="journal"` подразумевает, что тег с таким id уникальный на весь документ. Да и если значения будут разные, все-равно они выцепятся. Если что, в вопросе нужно это пояснять. И если данные могут меняться, то привести несколько наборов данных :) Например, вы могли привести пример данных в вопросе и указать что данные берутся из `<этой ссылки>`. Тогда, желающие могли по ней пройти и потестить с ней свой код. Просто, у вас в вопросе было про то как вытащить те данные и в ответе вы получили, что спросили :)